# not able to close modal dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Issue:**not able to close modal dialog**

I have the following code, it works for me, the dialog is opened.

```
$("#invitation-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Send Invitation',

    open: function() {
        $("#invitation-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('invitation_form.html')) %>")
    }
});
```

Inside the invitation form, after user click the "send" button,
it will trigger and function in the controller, it is and ajax call, coz i set :remote => true

and i try to do the following

```
$("#invitation-form").dialog("close")
```

the dialog does NOT close.

i put and alert message to test it, it run through the the code, i can see the alert message.

can anyone help me, how can i close the dialog?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code Where you called `dialog('close')`? Also, was there any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try setting the dialog up as not to `autoOpen`:

```
$("#invitation-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Send Invitation',

    open: function() {
        $("#invitation-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('invitation_form.html')) %>")
    }
});
```

And then you can just call `open` on page load if you want, and `close` whenever you want to as well:

```
$("#invitation-form").dialog("open");
$("#invitation-form").dialog("close");
```

Comment: wow....how come it turn out to be such simple.. i was that close to the solution.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the ajax function within the close?

```
$( "#invitation-form" ).dialog({
   close: function() { Ajax stuff here }
});
```

Otherwise, try setting the "send" button:

```
//getter
var buttons = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check jquery-ui and jquery.js not included in the loaded file.
It will stop workin the dialog close method if loaded twice.